# Naming a MkDir created folder using DMax on an autonumber field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a customer complaint database that is populated via Access form. Each entry is numbered by a sequential autonumber field to create a "Complaint Number". When the complaint is posted, I want to use MkDir to create a folder that can hold any documents or images related to the complaint. I want the folder name to be the complaint number name. The best solution I can find is to DMax + 1 the autonumber (Complaint Number) field.

I have managed to get the function (run off of a macro) to create the folder. However, I cannot figure out the DMax or naming piece.

```
Public Function makenewfolder()
 'create complaint number

Me.[Complaint Number] = DMax([Complaint Number], [tbl_Complaint_Problem_Log]) + 1

MsgBox "Complaint Number Generated"

'need code to create folder

If Dir("F:\Customer Complaints\" & Me.[Complaint Number], vbDirectory) = "" Then

  MkDir ("F:\Customer Complaints\" & Me.[Complaint Number])

Else

'do nothing for directory already exists

End If
End Function
```

I've received numerous error codes as I have tweaked the code, however I'm currently stuck on a

> 2465 - Microsoft Access can not find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.

Comment: You should include the error text and the line of code which triggers the error. Please use the [edit] link below the question to incorporate the information into the question, itself

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't pinpoint with 100% certainty where the error is occurring because debugging isn't providing an indication. However, I'm 95% certain it's happening here - Me.[Complaint Number] = DMax([Complaint Number], [tbl_Complaint_Problem_Log]) + 1 - as the code functioned on a basic level of creating a folder with a static name originally. It's either my "Me."  or the DMax that is problematic now.

Answer (score 0):

`DMax` needs **Strings** as parameters.

So you need something like

```
Me.[Complaint Number] = DMax("[Complaint Number]", "tbl_Complaint_Problem_Log") + 1
```

Comment: So I changed the parameter to the above and I'm still getting the 2465 error. I'll play with it some more and see where I get. Thanks.

Comment: Please check: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) @ThomasW.

Comment: I'm unable to step into the code as it's a forms module. I attempted to call it from a different module unsuccessfully. I did run it through the debugger under a different module and it was telling me improper use of Me.